# Strtok not creating a token

Tags: c, token, strtok, string-parsing

I am trying to parse a char * array into tokens and I am researching strtok. However whenever I run my code, it doesn't return anything into my temporary value and I was wondering what I was doing wrong

```
int length;
int i = 0;
int tokenCounter = 0;
int commandCounter = -1;
char *tempToken;

char tempInput[MAX_LINE];

length = read(STDIN_FILENO, tempInput, MAX_LINE);

commandCounter = -1;

if (length < 0)
{
    perror ("There was an error reading the command");
}
else if (length == 0)
{
    exit (0);
}
else
{
    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (tempInput[i] == "\n" || tempInput[i] == ' ' || tempInput == "\t")
        {
            /*
            if (commandCounter != -1)
            {
                pTokens[tokenCounter] = &tempInput[commandCounter];
                ++tokenCounter;
            }

            tempInput [i] = '\0';
            commandCounter = -1;
            */
        }
        else
        {
            tempToken = strtok (tempInput, " \n");

            while (tempToken != NULL)
            {
              strcpy(pTokens[tokenCounter], tempToken);
              tempToken = strtok (tempInput, " \n");
            }
            ++tokenCounter;
        }
    }
}
pTokens[tokenCounter] = NULL;
```

Comment: strtok takes string as the first argument only at first call...in the later calls you need to supply a NULL in first argument..

Comment: shouldn't you increment tokenCounter after using it as index?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't be surprised if `pTokens[]` isn't initialized with pointers that point to valid memory. I'd bet that `pTokens[tokenCounter] = strdup(tempToken);` would work better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tempToken = strtok (tempInput, " \n");
```

Other than the first time `NULL` pointer has to be passed to `strtok`, I mean inside the `while` loop, only `NULL` has to be passed instead of the string.

```
tempToken = strtok (NULL, " \n");
```

Answer (score 0):

the standard to use strtok() is fisrt use input then NULL as parameter. i.e. 
first time

```
strtok(input, delimeter)
```

after that for subsequent breaking of same input string use,

```
strtok(NULL,delimiter)
```

strtok() will take the previous input string.
there are many questions discussing about strtok() in stackoverflow itself. go through it to get more information.